# In Apache config all my attempts to redirect all requests to index.html fail

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, mod-rewrite

I have an Angular SPA that should only request index.html. All other URL requests to this server are handled internally by the SPA. I want to redirect all 404 errs to index.html.

[UPDATE: This post describes how I am trying to use mod_rewrite for this. Perhaps this is not what I should be doing.]

I am new to Apache configuration. Every solution that I found online for this fails. I was able to successfully add a re-write to redirect http traffic to https. So I assume that mod_rewrite should be set up correctly. But all my other attempts at a re-write fail. I am probably making some obvious newbee mistake.

I am runing:
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-10-14T16:24:43

After editing the config file, I always run "sudo systemctl reload apache2.

Here is my config file for my virtual host,  govmeeting.org.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName govmeeting.org
ServerAlias www.govmeeting.org
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# This re-directs http traffic to https. This works.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =govmeeting.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.govmeeting.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

# This was one solution I found to redirect all 404 errs to the main domain.
# It does NOT work. I still get 404 errs for govmeeting.org/somepage.
# ErrorDocument 404 https://govmeeting.org/

# This is another solution that I found that does NOT work:
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
#
# Here is another suggestion that does NOT work:
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
#
# In this, I tried to redirect "somepage" to index.html. Does NOT work.
# I tried with and without a second "RewriteEngine on", because the
# suggestion was using it twice.
# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteRule ^somepage$ index.html [NC]
#
# Here I added "/" before each file name. Does NOT work.
# RewriteEngine on
# Redirect /x.html /index.html

</VirtualHost>
```

UPDATE: I set up logging with:

```
LogLevel trace6 rewrite_module:trace6
```

I edited my config to only have this redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.html [NC]
```

I then sent requests from the browser for "govmeeting.org/dashboard", ".../xxx.txt" and ".../home.html".

Here is a tail of access.log:

```
114.119.156.56 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:03:03 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;PetalBot;+https://webmaster.petalsearch.com/site/petalbot)"
67.80.142.21 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:07:48 +0000] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 404 5729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
67.80.142.21 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:08:08 +0000] "-" 408 5213 "-" "-"
188.166.170.135 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:12:50 +0000] "GET /currentsetting.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 5607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
188.166.170.135 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:12:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 624 "-" "-"
67.80.142.21 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:19:58 +0000] "GET /xxx.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 5729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
67.80.142.21 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:20:18 +0000] "-" 408 5213 "-" "-"
67.80.142.21 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:25:06 +0000] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 404 5729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
67.80.142.21 - - [04/Dec/2021:02:25:26 +0000] "-" 408 5213 "-" "-"
```

Here is a tail of error.log. I am not sure how to interpret these results. The contents of the folder for my site only contains an index.html and a group of javascript files. (no "robots.txt", etc). Is it attempting to do a rewrite for these requests?

```
[Sat Dec 04 02:03:03.013635 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4283] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 114.119.156.56:18482] 114.119.156.56 - - [govmeeting.org/sid#7f337385b810][rid#7f337391a0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /robots.txt
[Sat Dec 04 02:03:03.013654 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4283] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 114.119.156.56:18482] 114.119.156.56 - - [govmeeting.org/sid#7f337385b810][rid#7f337391a0a0/initial] applying pattern '/^home.html$' to uri '/robots.txt'
[Sat Dec 04 02:03:03.013702 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4283] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 114.119.156.56:18482] 114.119.156.56 - - [govmeeting.org/sid#7f337385b810][rid#7f337391a0a0/initial] pass through /robots.txt

[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.122092 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4566] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:50802] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23ca000a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.122099 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4566] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:50802] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23ca000a0/initial] applying pattern '^home.html$' to uri '/'
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.122175 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4566] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:50802] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23ca000a0/initial] pass through /

[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.122306 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4566] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:50802] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23b1090a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.122311 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4566] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:50802] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23b1090a0/subreq] applying pattern '^home.html$' to uri '/index.html'
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.122316 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4566] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:50802] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23b1090a0/subreq] pass through /index.html

[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.195319 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4567] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:40432] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23ca000a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.195325 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4567] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:40432] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23ca000a0/initial] applying pattern '^home.html$' to uri '/'
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.195342 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4567] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:40432] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23ca000a0/initial] pass through /

[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.195467 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4567] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:40432] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23b1090a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.195472 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4567] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:40432] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23b1090a0/subreq] applying pattern '^home.html$' to uri '/index.html'
[Sat Dec 04 02:28:32.195476 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4567] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 167.248.133.59:40432] 167.248.133.59 - - [35.211.93.45/sid#7fd23b007810][rid#7fd23b1090a0/subreq] pass through /index.html
```

Comment: You seem to be defining all of your rewrites in the virtualhost for `http://` which you would likely want to move into the virtualhost for `https://` since your first action is to redirect all requests to `https://`.  You should check the [logs generated by `mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for debugging what is actually happening during rewrites.

Comment: I removed the action to redirect all requests to https:// and tried the other rewrites again. They still fail. So that doesn't appear to be the problem. But I will take your suggestion and set up logging for mod_rewrite and check  the logs.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I got the logs for mod_rewrite. I modified my post to include these results.

Comment: Looking at your added rewrite logs, I do not see anything being rewritten.  The message `applying pattern '^home.html$' to uri '/index.html'` says that it is checking the regex pattern `^home.html$` against the requested URI `/index.html` and since it does not match, the original URI is passed.  You stated that there is currently only one rule: `RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.html [NC]` which should take a request for `home.html` and rewrite it to `index.html`.  Does it rewrite correctly when you request `home.html`?

Comment: When I request `home.html`, I get a 404 error. I think the requests for `/` and `index.html` happened automatically when I opened Chrome and it retried the link that was in the address bar. It does appear that I'm missing messages from the rewrite log. I actually opened a new post to address this specific issue: [missing messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679916/in-apache-config-all-my-attempts-to-redirect-all-requests-to-index-html-fail)